# Web API Delete method throws 404 for from angular application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am working on an Angular application that consumes c# web api :

This is how Delete look like in WebApi :

```
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var cakeToDelete = await _CakeRepositry.Get(id);
        if(cakeToDelete == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        await _CakeRepositry.Delete(_CakeRepositry.Id);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Service in Angular :

```
 deleteCake(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete<any>("https://localhost:44370/api/Cakes/Delete/id?="+id);
   }
```

Call to delete method throws **404** error:

However, everything works fine from **Swagger**:

I am not getting what went wrong, please help me.

Comment: url should be `"https://localhost:44370/api/Cakes/Delete?id=" + id`

Comment: With this URL too it thors 404 error

Comment: From the given base url out of your angular code and the attribute route I would guess on `https://localhost:44370/api/Cakes/1234`. (While `1234` should be your real id)

Comment: Also cause id is an integer the attribute route should better be `[HttpDelete("{id:int}")]`

Comment: If it really works from swagger, then take a sharp look onto the url that swagger shows in the response as response url after pressing execute. There must be a typo to your angular url.

Comment: Error 404 is the URI is not found.  May be the ID is different.